# AWSにデプロイ時にUnicornが起動しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, unicorn

お世話になっております。
下記の問題について知見がある方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示お願いします。

## 起きている問題

```
$ bundle exec unicorn_rails -c /var/www/rails/coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb -D -E production
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn_rails (/home/ryouya/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/unicorn_rails)
SyntaxError: /var/www/rails/coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
  end
  ^~~
  /home/ryouya/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/unicorn-
:
(省略)
:
  /home/ryouya/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

AWS上のUnicornが起動しません。

```
SyntaxError: /var/www/rails/coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

エラー文としては`unicorn.conf.rb`で`end`が多いという指摘をもらっているのですが、
`end`の数は合っている認識です。

unicorn.conf.rb

```
  $worker  = 2
  $timeout = 30
  $app_dir = "/var/www/rails/coffee_app”
  $listen  = File.expand_path 'tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock', $app_dir
  $pid     = File.expand_path 'tmp/pids/unicorn.pid', $app_dir
  $std_log = File.expand_path 'log/unicorn.log', $app_dir
  # set config
  worker_processes  $worker
  working_directory $app_dir
  stderr_path $std_log
  stdout_path $std_log
  timeout $timeout
  listen  $listen
  pid $pid
  # loading booster
  preload_app true
  # before starting processes
  before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
    if old_pid != server.pid
      begin
        Process.kill "QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i
      rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      end
    end
  end
  after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
```

## 試したこと

#### endを１つ無くす

別のエラーが発生しました。

```
$ bundle exec unicorn_rails -c /var/www/rails/coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb -D -E production
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn_rails (/home/ryouya/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/unicorn_rails)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `old_pid' for #<Unicorn::Configurator:0x000000000164f540>
  /var/www/rails/coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb:23:in `reload'
:
(省略)
:
  /home/ryouya/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

#### EC2を再起動

問題解決にはなりませんでした。

## 関連ファイル

unicorn.conf.rb

```
$worker  = 2
  $timeout = 30
  $app_dir = "/var/www/rails/coffee_app”
  $listen  = File.expand_path 'tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock', $app_dir
  $pid     = File.expand_path 'tmp/pids/unicorn.pid', $app_dir
  $std_log = File.expand_path 'log/unicorn.log', $app_dir
  # set config
  worker_processes  $worker
  working_directory $app_dir
  stderr_path $std_log
  stdout_path $std_log
  timeout $timeout
  listen  $listen
  pid $pid
  # loading booster
  preload_app true
  # before starting processes
  before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
    if old_pid != server.pid
      begin
        Process.kill "QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i
      rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      end
    end
  end
  after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
```

## 環境

ruby 2.5.1
rails 5.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $app_dir = "/var/www/rails/coffee_app”

この行の最後のダブルクォートがいわゆる半角の「"」ではないため、

> old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"

の最初のダブルクォートまでが文字列として認識されているようです。シンタックスハイライトが変になっていることで気が付きました。

> $app_dir = "/var/www/rails/coffee_app"

と半角のクォートに直すと直ると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。全角から半角に直したところUnicoronが正常に起動いたしました！ありがとうございました！！m(_ _)m